Flutter error when passing data from child to parent screen(executing order)
first of all sorry for the messed up english, as it is not my first language.
So I'm trying to build a car rental app that uses maps api from google in flutter, I basically have a button to get the current location and after getting that location I want to pop the screen and get the saved data back to the parent screen as seen below
CHILD SCREEN
void savePlace(double lat, double lng) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng&key=myapikey');

    final response = await http.get(url);

    final resData = json.decode(response.body);
    final address = resData['results'][0]["formatted_address"];

    pickedLocation = PickupLocation(
      latitude: lat,
      longitude: lng,
      address: address,
    );
    isGettingLocation = false;
    print("this first");
    print(pickedLocation);

    if (pickedLocation == null) {
      return;
    }
  }

after executing the code above I pop the pickedLocation data using the navigator pop function from flutter and thus the part where I print "this first" should run before I pop the screen because I put it before the pop screen, however in the parent screen the other code is run first
PARENT SCREEN
  void locationData() async {
    final selectedLocation = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (ctx) => ParentScreen(),
    ));

      setState(() {
        pickedLocation = selectedLocation;
      });
    

    print("should be second");
    print(pickedLocation);
  }

below is the output that is given by the debug console
I/flutter ( 7909): should be second
I/flutter ( 7909): null
I/flutter ( 7909): this first
I/flutter ( 7909): Instance of 'PickupLocation'

the pickedLocation became null because of it ran first instead of waiting for the selectedlocationdata is given
do tell me if you need extra information

That's a long code sample. Can you reduce it to the minimum example that shows the behaviour you are trying to fix? stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (The process of reducing your code to the minimum example often shows you where your error is.) Also, can you make your title more specific? It looks like you are asking about execution order so you might want to mention that in the title.

Hi, thanks for the input, will do that!

I fixed the problem already, I simply run flutter clean and rebuild the app and the problem is fixed

using this code may be your error can be resolved

Navigator.Push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => ParentScreen())).then((value) {
                        setState((){
                          pickedLocation = selectedLocation;
                        });
                      });

remove await keyword if not necessary


Hi, thanks for answering but I fixed my problem already in the answer above, thank you
